# git branching - merging feature branch to release and dev branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

is it possible to merge a feature branch to 2 branches ?
scenario: dev branch is used to push daily changes to UAT for tests. A release branch is created for final push to production. we have feature/bug branches which the dev uses to commit code
IS it possible to first create a PR to the develop branch and ones validated in UAT have this pushed to the release branch? if the development isnt approved then the code remains in the development branch.

to give you more details .. if we want to only merge Feature A and C and not include feature B in the next release .. whats the best way to proceed? is cherry picking the only option we have?
[image]

Comment: to give you more details ..

Answer (score 0):

After you merged your feature branch --> dev, you have two possibilities :

- if you have one release branch, then rebase release branch on dev :

```
git checkout release

git rebase dev
```

- or create a new release branch from dev, with the number of version like release/2.2.10

Comment: can we keep the feature branch active and do a final merge directly to the release branch? i wish to push the code to UAT first and have the final merge done on the release branch which is connected to the production

Comment: with the 2 solutions that I proposed, the code of your feature branch will be in the release branch